# Optimizing Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently starting to work with Neo4J and it's query language cypher.
I have a multple queries that follow the same pattern.

I am doing some comparison between a SQL-Database and Neo4J.

In my Neo4J Datababase I habe one type of label (person) and one type of relationship (FRIENDSHIP). The person has the propterties personID, name, email, phone.
Now I want to have the the friends n-th degree. I also want to filter out those persons that are also friends with a lower degree.
FOr example if I want to search for the friends 3 degree I want to filter out those that are also friends first and/or second degree.

Here my query type:

```
MATCH (me:person {personID:'1'})-[:FRIENDSHIP*3]-(friends:person)
WHERE NOT (me:person)-[:FRIENDSHIP]-(friends:person)
AND NOT (me:person)-[:FRIENDSHIP*2]-(friends:person)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT friends);
```

I found something similiar somewhere.

This query works.

My problem is that this pattern of query is much to slow if I search for a higher degree of friendship and/or if the number of persons becomes more.

So I would really appreciate it, if somemone could help me with optimize this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to handle depths of 3, this should return the distinct nodes that are 3 degrees away but not also less than 3 degrees away:

```
MATCH (me:person {personID:'1'})-[:FRIENDSHIP]-(f1:person)-[:FRIENDSHIP]-(f2:person)-[:FRIENDSHIP]-(f3:person)
RETURN apoc.coll.subtract(COLLECT(f3), COLLECT(f1) + COLLECT(f2) + me) AS result;
```

The above query uses the APOC function [apoc.coll.subtract](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) to remove the unwanted nodes from the result. The function also makes sure the collection contains distinct elements.

The following query is more general, and should work for any given depth (by just replacing the number after `*`). For example, this query will work with a depth of 4:

```
MATCH p=(me:person {personID:'1'})-[:FRIENDSHIP*4]-(:person)
WITH NODES(p)[0..-1] AS priors, LAST(NODES(p)) AS candidate
UNWIND priors AS prior
RETURN apoc.coll.subtract(COLLECT(DISTINCT candidate), COLLECT(DISTINCT prior)) AS result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Cypher's variable-length relationship matching is that it's looking for all possible paths to that depth. This can cause unnecessary performance issues when all you're interested in are the nodes at certain depths and not the paths to them.

[APOC's path expander](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) using 'NODE_GLOBAL' `uniqueness` is a more efficient means of matching to nodes at inclusive depths.

When using 'NODE_GLOBAL' uniqueness, nodes are only ever visited once during traversal. Because of this, when we set the path expander's `minLevel` and `maxLevel` to be the same, the result are nodes at that level that are not present at any lower level, which is exactly the result you're trying to get.

Try this query after installing APOC:

```
MATCH (me:person {personID:'1'})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(me, {uniqueness:'NODE_GLOBAL', minLevel:4, maxLevel:4}) YIELD path
// a single path for each node at depth 4 but not at any lower depth
RETURN COUNT(path)
```

Of course you'll want to parameterize your inputs (personID, level) when you get the chance.